# Error assigning value to JavaScript class property

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, synchronization, prompt

I am getting an error while setting a class property in javascript class. I am using nodejs prompt module to get user input and setting it to the class property. But i am getting following error.

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'resultAge' of undefined**

I figured it out that it has something to do with **synchronization**, but i am not able to figure it out that how to implement it for this situation.

Also i want to prompt user again until he has entered a valid number (I can not use a do while loop, what might be the solution?)

```
var prompt = require("prompt");

var ageTotal =  function(){
    this.resultAge = 0;

    this.getUserAge = function(){
        prompt.start();

        //i want to run this until valid input is entered
        prompt.get(["age"], function(err, result){

            //I know i have to convert userInput to int but thats for later
            this.resultAge += result.age

        });
    }
}

ageTotal.prototype.displayTotalAge = function(){
    return this.resultAge;
}

var a = new ageTotal();
a.getUserAge();


   var age = a.displayTotalAge();
console.log(age);   //This is running before the above function finishes
```

***EDIT:***
*The problem setting resultAge is solved but now the problem is  **var age = a.displayTotalAge();** is evaluated after console.log(age) which results in **0**;*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the scope of `ageTotal` into the `prompt.get` callback:

```
var ageTotal =  function(){
    this.resultAge = 0;

    this.getUserAge = function(){
        var that = this;
        prompt.start();

        prompt.get(["age"], function(err, result){
            that.resultAge += result.age
        });
    }
}
```